# How does the Eclipse CDT indexer cooperate with version control?

Tags: git, version-control, clearcase, eclipse-cdt

I use both Git and ClearCase for different projects.  I always wonder how the Eclipse CDT indexer cooperates (or not!) with the underlying version control.

For example, when you "git checkout" another branch, or in ClearCase change your config spec, the entire source tree could change underneath you.  The index needs to be refreshed or rebuilt.

Are there any tips/tricks people have?  E.g. where to store the workspace, which options to check, which commands to run?

Answer (score 1):

One feature you can use is the [Scanner Discovery](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn81#Scanner_Discovery), also described in [the FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_heard_that_CDT_can_parse_output_of_my_build_and_set_includes_.28-I.29_and_macros_.28-D.29_per_file_but_it_never_seems_to_work_for_me.) and integrated in Eclipse Juno:

> CDT can parse output of my build and set includes (-I) and macros (-D) per file

That can be useful when sources changes and the build is triggered again.
Besides that, it is mainly `View-->select Index-->rebuild` when a ClearCase view or git working tree changes.
The ClearCase `view.dat` or the `.git` repo metadata are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, VonC. (BTW, I read lots of your posts regarding Git/ClearCase... they are very helpful, thank you).  Too bad if rebuilding the entire index is the only option, considering a small portion of the working tree may be changed. But this is the only reliable method I have found.

Comment: @jfritz42 I agree. I didn't found a reliable incremental index rebuild.